# Why does an ajax call to a Java program dumps all its code onto the screen instead of simply printing out what I tell it to?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

My ultimate goal on this project is to have the client use an ajax call to post to a Java program, query the database and return the results to my web page. For the purposes of this question I'm simply asking Java to print out a simple greeting but right now all it's doing is dumping all the code onto the screen.

Here is my ajax call:

```
getText = function(duty){

$.ajax({

type: "POST",

url: 'querymanager.java',

data: (duty),

success: function(data){

console.log(data);

}

});

}
```

And here is the Java program it calls:

```
class MyTestClass{

public static void main(String args[]){

try{

System.out.println('And here is the text to return to my website');

}

}
```

Comment: querymanager.java needs to be compile to a .class before it can be run, and the mechanism of invoking it remotely from a webpage in your browser involves an HTTP GET or POST call to a server running the code somewhere. This also implies the Java app is deployed somewhere and exposes a HTTP endpoint to be called. There are many ways of doing this, e.g. it could be a servlet running on a servlet container on an app server, and/or it could be using frameworks like Jersey or Spring Boot. You seem to have missed some significant steps in your implementation so far.

Comment: Using the Spring framework, this might give you some ideas https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Answer (score 2):

Your java function cannot be invoked directly like that in you JS script

url: querymanager.java - Wrong

You need to have an http endpoint that will invoke this function and return you the results.

Implementation is beyond scope.